# Weblogic Admin console Login Issue

Tags: validation, authentication, weblogic, schema

Today i tried to create one queue and activate the changes. But during activating, got one error `cvc-enumeration-valid: string value 'No-Delivery' is not a valid enumeration value for delivery-mode-type`.

Without discarding the changes, i stopped admin server and executed the start script. Then the server came in running mode as per log. But when entered valid user credential and tried LOGIN, getting the below error in log and error page is redirected:

```
--> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/jsp/common/CriticalError.jsp.> 

-->> [weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@fba6318 - appName: 'consoleapp', name: 'console', context-path: '/console', spec-version: '2.5'] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.objectIfCommitted(ServletResponseImpl.java:1553)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(ServletResponseImpl.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:136)

-->><AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1458043812532> <BEA-141244> <Schema validation errors while parsing jms/gerpjmsmodule-jms.xml - string value 'No-Delivery' is not a valid enumeration value for delivery-mode-type in namespace http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-jms> 
-->>Console encountered the following error java.lang.RuntimeException: weblogic.management.provider.EditFailedException: 
        at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit.internal.EditServiceMBeanImpl.getDomainConfiguration(EditServiceMBeanImpl.java:67)


-->>[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@fba6318 - appName: 'consoleapp', name: 'console', context-path: '/console', spec-version: '2.5'] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.objectIfCommitted(ServletResponseImpl.java:1553)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(ServletResponseImpl.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0):

From attached snippets I can see below error.

```
<Schema validation errors while parsing jms/gerpjmsmodule-jms.xml - string value 'No-Delivery' is not a valid enumeration value for delivery-mode-type in namespace http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-jms>
```

There is something wrong with the JMS Module configured. Can you try to untarget this module and try to start server?

Untarget it from config.xml manually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an old version of weblogic (older than 10.3.4).

This is a known bug, more details can be found from:
http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/11/weblogic-bug-when-setting-override.html

There you can find workarounds, and in 10.3.4 was solved by bug:
8617285     Administration Console  10.3.4  JMS Message Bridges cannot be targeted to Migratable Targets via the Administration Console.